# Autosys, FileWatcher Job, passing if the file is not present, is it possible?

Tags: autosys, file-watcher

I am new to Autosys, and looking for a way to achieve reverse of file watching

I am looking for a job similar to file watcher, which keeps on running till the file is present, and will only pass if the file is not present. The dependent job will only if the file is not present.

there are few 
   1) I am not sure if I can achieve this with fileWatcher. 
   2) Does FileWatcher job stops running after it finds the file,
   3) is there any way to negate the success condition for filewatcher job.

Or if anyone can provide me some good extensive document on FileWatcher, that would be a help too.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with filewatcher job alone.
Filewatcher jobs stops running and goes to Success state as soon as it finds the file in the defined path. There is no way to negate its Success state.

This is so as its assumed that such functionalities can be easily implemented by scripts.

You can achieve what you want by batch script(Windows) or Shell Script(Unix/Linux). A script can be triggered by the Autosys job which checks file presence at place you intend, then sleeps for some time ( say 20 secs) checks again, and sends exit code 0 if it finally doesn't find the file, or some other exit code if after certain checks file didnt move eventually.

You can keep downstream jobs depended on this Autosys job as per requirement.

Let me know if more clarification is needed on this.